# laravel 5.2 how to protect route only for authenticated user

Tags: php, laravel-5

i'm new to laravel, i had installed auth scaffold, here is the route up to now.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');    


    Route::get('addthreadhtml', function()
    {
        return View::make('addThreadForm');
    });
    Route::post('thread/add', 'ThreadController@addthread');
    Route::get('thread/showall', 'ThreadController@showallthread');

});
```

i want to protect addthreadhtml from non-authenticated user access, if the user don't login, they will be redirected to another view.

How can i do that?

Comment: You should google "access control list laravel" https://mattstauffer.co/blog/acl-access-control-list-authorization-in-laravel-5-1

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/protecting-admin-routes-laravel-42

Comment: Use the `auth` middleware: https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the auth for the function only, you can put this on the top code

```
if(!Auth::user('id')){
   //redirect to any view not require auth
}
```

or this code

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the auth middleware to the route you want to protect:

```
Route::get('addthreadhtml', ['middleware' => 'auth', function () {
    return View::make('addThreadForm');
}]);
```